# nodejs - prints undefined on calling function in another js file

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js

I am getting below error on executing code below :

```
Failed: path must be a string
Stack:
  TypeError: path must be a string
      at TypeError (native)
      at Object.fs.readFile (fs.js:250:11)
```

The code being ran is as below:

```
this.getNodeValueFromXML = function(xmlPath,node){
    var self = this;
    try {
        var file = path.join(__dirname, xmlPath)
        fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
            if(err){
                logger.warnLogger(err,'Error while processing XML file!!');
            }
            else{
                parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                    if(err){
                        logger.warnLogger(err,'Not a valid file!!');
                    }
                    else {
                        var value=self.getValueFromJson(result,node);
                        return value;
                    }
              });
            }
        });
    }
    catch(e){
        if (e.code !== 'ENOENT') {
            throw e
        } else {
            logger.warnLogger(e,'File not found!'); 
        }
    }
};
```

I am calling this `function` from other js file using below syntax

```
commonFunction.getNodeValueFromXML("../my.xml",'user.name');
```

Earlier it was giving error  `Failed: path must be a string Stack:`. After making the changes as `path.join(__dirname, xmlPath)`, it works but calling same function from another `js` file prints undefined.

Can someone help

Comment: use `path.join(__dirname, '../my.xml')`

Comment: Still giving the same error

Comment: @Abhinav I just called your function in same file with some static file path and it's working fine and getting "File not found!!", Can you recheck your error and line number on your file?

Comment: Can you let me know where you have used `path.join(__dirname, '../my.xml')`

Comment: It is working but calling same function from another js file prints undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `path.join(__dirname, '../my.xml')` for solving below issue:

```
Failed: path must be a string
Stack:
  TypeError: path must be a string
      at TypeError (native)
      at Object.fs.readFile (fs.js:250:11)
```

For calling function from another file I modified code to use `callback` function.